# Nodelet zero-copy doesn't seem to work, source and destination addresses don't match

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the title says, I am trying to essentially "prove" that zero copy between nodelets works and I'm having trouble. I've got a ZeroCopyTestSenderNodelet as follows:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nodelet/nodelet.h"
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
namespace ros_test_package
{
    class ZeroCopyTestSenderNodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet
    {
    public:
        inline virtual void onInit()
        {
            NODELET_INFO("[ZeroCopyTestSender]\tInitializing...");
            count_ = 0;
            getPrivateNodeHandle().param("rate", rate_, double(0.5));
            pub_ = getNodeHandle().advertise<std_msgs::Int32>("test_int", 1);
            pub_loop_ = getNodeHandle().createTimer(ros::Duration(1.0f/rate_), boost::bind(&ZeroCopyTestSenderNodelet::pubLoopFunc, this, _1));
            NODELET_INFO("[ZeroCopyTestSender]\tInitialized.");
        };
        inline void pubLoopFunc(const ros::TimerEvent& event)
        {
            std_msgs::Int32 this_int_msg;
            this_int_msg.data = count_++;
            NODELET_INFO("[ZeroCopyTestSender]\t--> value %d, address 0x%08X...", this_int_msg.data, &(this_int_msg.data));
            pub_.publish(this_int_msg);
            ros::spinOnce();
        }
    private:
        ros::Publisher pub_;
        ros::Timer pub_loop_;
        double rate_;
        int count_;
    };
} // namespace ros_test_package
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(ros_test_package::ZeroCopyTestSenderNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet)
```

and a ZeroCopyTestReceiverNodelet as follows:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nodelet/nodelet.h"
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int32.h>
namespace ros_test_package
{
    class ZeroCopyTestReceiverNodelet : public nodelet::Nodelet
    {
    public:
        inline virtual void onInit()
        {
            NODELET_INFO("[ZeroCopyTestReceiver]\tInitializing...");
            sub_ = getNodeHandle().subscribe("test_int", 1, &ZeroCopyTestReceiverNodelet::callback, this);
            NODELET_INFO("[ZeroCopyTestReceiver]\tInitialized.");
        };
        inline void callback(const std_msgs::Int32ConstPtr test_int_msg)
        {
            NODELET_INFO("[ZeroCopyTestReceiver]\t<-- value %d, address 0x%08X.", test_int_msg->data, &(test_int_msg->data));
        }
    private:
        ros::Subscriber sub_;
    };
} // namespace ros_test_package
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(ros_test_package::ZeroCopyTestReceiverNodelet, nodelet::Nodelet)
```

I am launching a sender and two receivers on the same manager using the following:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="zero_copy_test_manager" args="manager" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="zero_copy_test_sender_nodelet" args="load ros_test_package/ZeroCopyTestSenderNodelet zero_copy_test_manager" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="zero_copy_test_receiver_nodelet" args="load ros_test_package/ZeroCopyTestReceiverNodelet zero_copy_test_manager" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="zero_copy_test_receiver_nodelet2" args="load ros_test_package/ZeroCopyTestReceiverNodelet zero_copy_test_manager" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

The output of running this is as follows, and is similar regardless if there is only 1 or 2 receivers launched:

```
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252429.626189985] Initializing nodelet with 12 worker threads.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252429.635256318] [ZeroCopyTestSender] Initializing...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252429.638284332] [ZeroCopyTestSender] Initialized.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252429.649166515] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   Initializing...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252429.655558553] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   Initialized.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252429.659189946] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   Initializing...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252429.663768935] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   Initialized.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252431.639207762] [ZeroCopyTestSender] --> value 0, address 0x0CF8E46C...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252431.640040360] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 0, address 0xE40017CC.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252431.640214038] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 0, address 0xE40017CC.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252433.639092537] [ZeroCopyTestSender] --> value 1, address 0x0CF8E46C...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252433.639549131] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 1, address 0xE40017CC.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252433.639722691] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 1, address 0xE40017CC.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252435.638775083] [ZeroCopyTestSender] --> value 2, address 0x0CF8E46C...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252435.639248751] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 2, address 0xE400182C.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252435.639409818] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 2, address 0xE400182C.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252437.638406888] [ZeroCopyTestSender] --> value 3, address 0x0CF8E46C...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252437.638697812] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 3, address 0xE400182C.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252437.638795855] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 3, address 0xE400182C.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252439.639133032] [ZeroCopyTestSender] --> value 4, address 0x0CF8E46C...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252439.639587543] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 4, address 0xD800151C.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252439.639744379] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 4, address 0xD800151C.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252441.638872904] [ZeroCopyTestSender] --> value 5, address 0x0CF8E46C...
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252441.639297394] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 5, address 0xE400182C.
[/zero_copy_test_manager@1610252441.639488512] [ZeroCopyTestReceiver]   <-- value 5, address 0xE400182C.
```

As you can see, the sender address never changes and each iteration the receiver addresses are the same but differ on each iteration (usually, though not always) and never match that of the sender. I would expect the address of the sender and receivers to be the same for each iteration (though change from iteration to iteration, since I'm re-instantiating the msg in the sender each time - re-instantiating each time vs letting the msg be a member of the nodelet class doesn't seem to affect anything either). Any idea what's going wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369176/nodelet-zero-copy-doesn%27t-seem-to-work,-source-and-destination-addresses-don%27t-match/) by [mmiles19](https://answers.ros.org/users/26411/mmiles19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have this in your timer callback:

```
inline void pubLoopFunc(const ros::TimerEvent& event)
{
    std_msgs::Int32 this_int_msg;
    [..]
    pub_.publish(this_int_msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
}
```

to be able to skip the serialisation step, `roscpp` needs a pointer, and your message object created on the heap.
This makes sense, as how would it provide your `this_int_msg` to subscribers after it has gone out of scope?

From the [wiki/nodelet](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) page, section [Publishing from a Nodelet](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet#Publishing_from_a_Nodelet):

> If you want the no-copy pub/sub to work you must publish your messages as `shared_ptrs`. See [roscpp/Overview/Publishers and Subscribers#Intraprocess_Publishing](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Intraprocess_Publishing) for more details.

The linked page then shows the following example:

```
ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("topic_name", 5);
std_msgs::StringPtr str(new std_msgs::String);
str->data = "hello world";
pub.publish(str);
```

You'll have to adapt your publishing nodelet to do this as well. I would expect your `INFO` messages to show matching addresses after you've made those changes.

(you could of course use `std::make_shared<..>(..)`, I believe the example is from before we had C++11)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-10**:
An additional comment: calling `spinOnce()` yourself in a callback is typically unnecessary, and in the case of nodelets even more so I believe. The manager already runs spinner(s) for you.

**Comment by [mmiles19](https://answers.ros.org/users/26411/mmiles19/) on 2021-01-11**:
This was it! Thanks so much! I had tried making this_int_msg a member but hadn't tried making it a pointer. Thanks again!

**Comment by [mmiles19](https://answers.ros.org/users/26411/mmiles19/) on 2021-01-11**:
As a follow up, could you explain how even when the msg it created on the heap, it seems to be coming from the same address (0x0CF8E46C)? Is this a compiler optimization or something?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-11**:\

> As a follow up, could you explain how even when the msg it created on the heap, it seems to be coming from the same address? Is this a compiler optimization or something?

It's bad form to ask follow-up questions in comments under answers to other questions. Visibility is practically zero for such follow-ups. It would be better to ask a new question (possibly while referring to this one).